# Why invariant generic type parameterized with subclass of upper bounds fails to conform?

Tags: scala, generics, inheritance, existential-type, invariance

Given:

```
class Invar[T]
trait ExtendsAnyref extends AnyRef
def f(a: Invar[ExtendsAnyref]) = {}
```

The following is erroneous

```
scala> val x: Function1[Invar[_ <: AnyRef], Unit] = f
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Invar[ExtendsAnyref] => Unit
 required: Invar[_ <: AnyRef] => Unit
       val x: Function1[Invar[_ <: AnyRef], Unit] = f
                                                    ^
```

Why?

I understand that in Scala, generic types have by
default nonvariant subtyping.  Thus, in the context of this example, instances of `Invar` with different type parameters would never be in a subtype relationship with each other.  So an `Invar[ExtendsAnyref]` would not be usable as a `Invar[AnyRef]`.

But I am confused about the meaning of `_ <: AnyRef` which I understood to mean "some type below `AnyRef` in the type hierarchy."  `ExtendsAnyref` is some type below `AnyRef` in the type hierarchy, so I would expect `Invar[ExtendsAnyref]` to conform to `Invar[_ <: AnyRef]`.

I understand that function objects are contravariant in their input-parameter types, but since I use `Invar[_ <: AnyRef]` rather than `Invar[AnyRef]` I understood, apparently incorrectly, the use of the upper bounds would have the meaning "`Invar` parameterized with `Anyref` or any extension thereof."

What am I missing?

Comment: "Invar parameterized with Anyref or any extension thereof." This is correct. And it is also the answer to your question: you want a function that takes `Invar[AnyRef]`, but instead are creating a function that takes what you wrote above. That's a different type.

Comment: "you want a function that takes `Invar[AnyRef]`..."

But I don't want that.  I want a function that takes `Invar` parameterized with **any subclass of `AnyRef`**.  You say that what I wrote excludes the "subclass of" part, but if the upper limit `_ <:` doesn't do that, what does it do?

Comment: Ok, the other way around: you want a function " that takes Invar parameterized with any subclass of AnyRef", but are giving it a function that takes `Invar[AnyRef]` .That's a different type.
The property of being a different type is commutative, so it does not matter: if A is not the same type as B, then B is not the same type as A.

Comment: You lost me.  Where am I "giving it a function that takes `Invar[AnyRef]`?" The function `f()` takes an argument of type `Invar[ExtendsAnyref]`, and in fact the error message says `found   : Invar[ExtendsAnyref] => Unit`.  What function are you talking about that takes `Invar[AnyRef]`?

Comment: Yes, a typo, sorry. You give it `[ExtendsAnyRef]` it wants `[_ extends AnyRef]`. You keep missing the point though: doesn't matter what exact types they are, what matters is that they are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
val x: Function1[Invar[_ <: AnyRef], Unit] = ...
```

it means `x` must accept *any* `Invar[_ <: AnyRef]`. That is, it must accept `Invar[AnyRef]`, `Invar[String]`, etc. `f` obviously doesn't: it only accepts `Invar[ExtendsAnyref]`.

In other words, you need to combine your last two paragraphs: because functions are contravariant in argument types, for `Function1[Invar[ExtendsAnyref], Unit]` to conform to `Function1[Invar[_ <: AnyRef], Unit]` you'd need `Invar[_ <: AnyRef]` to conform to `Invar[ExtendsAnyref]`, not vice versa.

If you

> want a function that takes Invar parameterized with any subclass of AnyRef

this can be written as `Function1[Invar[A], Unit] forSome { type A <: AnyRef }`. However, I don't believe there is anything useful you could do with an object of this type, because 1) the only thing you can do with a function is to apply it to an argument, but 2) you don't know what arguments this function accepts.